# How can I join 4 tables using SQL to get a result

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a simple database schema, according to the schema, I would like to find the highest salary among all employees, presenting the information about that employee (a_id, a_name, b_area).

There will be only one result return from table D and I try to return the employment_id to link with other tables but then it returns more than 1 result. Please check my query underneath, thank you very much :)
[image]

```
SELECT
     a.a_id,
     a.a_name,
     b.b_area 
FROM
     A a, B b, C c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.employee_id, MAX(d.salary) FROM D d)
     ON d.employee_id= c.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with D, then join the other tables as needed:

```
... D left join c on (d.employee_id = c.employee_id) left join a on ...
```

And the highest salary bit would be something like:

```
... where salary = (select max(salary) from d)
```

Keep in mind that this will return multiple results if there is more than one employee having the maximum salary.

Comment: what if I want to find the largest salary (which is a comparison between last year and this year salary: `MAX(L_SALARY - N_SALARY)`)?

Comment: You don't have that data in the model in your question, so it's hard to give you any advice on that. Perhaps it's a different question?

Comment: actually the schema is a modified one, under table D, it also has the column of L_SALARY(last year salary) and N_SALARY(this year salary)

Comment: Then `MAX(N_SALARY - L_SALARY)` will give you record(s) with highest salary rise.

Comment: so it would be something like `where m_salary = (select max(N_SALARY- L_SALARY))`?

Answer (score 0):

You miss a join condition for your tables. This should do what you need.

```
SELECT a.a_id, a.a_name, b.b_area 
FROM C
JOIN A ON a.a_id = c.a_id
JOIN B ON b.b_id = c.c_id
JOIN D ON d.employee_id = c.employee_id    
WHERE d.salary = (SELECT max(salary) FROM D)
```

Comment: if I add a condition to the highest salary, would it be `d.salary = (SELECT max(salary) FROM D WHERE xxx = yyy);`? @Radim Bača

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

**Subselect-Solution:**

```
 SELECT A.a_name
       ,B.b_area
       ,maxsalary.MaxSal
   FROM
      (
        SELECT D.employee_id
              ,MAX(D.Salary) as MaxSal
          FROM D
      GROUP BY D.employee
      ) maxsalary
    INNER JOIN C
            ON C.employee_id = maxsalary.employee_id
    INNER JOIN B
            ON C.b_id = B.b_id
    INNER JOIN A
            ON C.a_id = A.a_id
```

This solution might be more performant. As `SUBSELECT` maxsalary will return just one row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use HAVING Clause,

```
SELECT a.a_id, a.a_name, b.b_area FROM A a, B b, C c LEFT JOIN D d ON c.employee_id = d.employee_id
GROUP BY d.salary
HAVING MAX(d.salary);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT D.*, a.a_name, b.b_area FROM D
LEFT JOIN c ON d.employee_id = c.employee_id
LEFT JOIN a ON a.a_id = c.a_id
LEFT JOIN b ON b.b_id = c.a_id
ORDER BY D.salary DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will output one row as:

employee_id | salary | a_name | b_area

Comment: what if I want to find the largest salary (which is a comparison between last year and this year salary: MAX(L_SALARY - N_SALARY))?